# Geoserver CSS line with different colors

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I want to visualize a line with Geoserver with multiple colors with CSS. Each 3 px, another color has to show. So I have red, green and yellow and I want a line with this 3 colors, each 3 px color should change. Is this possible with CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to draw three dashed lines offset from each other so that a complete line is drawn. So first you draw a red dashed line with 3 pixel dashes and 6 pixel spaces, then an blue line with a 3 pixel offset and then 3 pixels and 6 spaces and the same for the green line.

In SLD this would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>mulitcolor</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A red line style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>red line</Title>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray" >6 12</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#00ff00</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray" >6 12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dashoffset">6</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000ff</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray" >6 12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dashoffset">12</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

This gives a line like this (though I doubled everything to make is more visible):

[image]

You can do the same in [CSS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/properties.html#line-symbology) ([dasharray example](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cookbook/line.html#dashed-line)) if that is your prefered language.

Answer (score 1):

Geoserver uses SLD stylesheets by default. They are relatively simple and intuitive to use. You can acces them via Data/Styles in the main window.
Geoserver has detailed documentation on this:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/index.html

There is also css extension that allows you to use css instead (it is converted to sld by geoserver): http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if I should make a new question, but since a CSS example was mentioned it would be good with a full example. The doc only show example of dashed line with a single colour, not for different colours. I cannot quite figure out how to style the same line twice?

I tried this but it does not work

```
* {
    stroke: #000000;
    z-index: 1
}

* {
    stroke: #ffff00;
    stroke-dasharray: 5 2;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    z-index: 2
}
```